# how to declare a void in constructor c#?

Tags: c#

I found this code (no conpiler error, it's mean code no error) that is "PingCompletedEventHandler" has constructor like PingCompletedEventHandler(abc) with static void abc(object s, PingCompletedEventArgs e){} right?

```
    static PingCompletedEventHandler Ping_completed(object s, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This code work fine, it used method void abc below 
        PingCompletedEventHandler a = new PingCompletedEventHandler(abc);
        value.Add("abc");   
        lock (@lock)
        {
            instances -= 1;
        }
        if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            string abcd = string.Concat("Active IP: ", e.Reply.Address.ToString());
            value.Add("abc");
            value.Add(abcd);
            result += 1;
        }
        return a;
    }

    static void abc(object s, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

How can they do this. I have tested in my code, it doesn't work. Here is my test:

```
class Class1
{
    static void abcd(int a){
    }
    public 
// Error here: Class1.abcd(int)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'
    Class1(abcd)
    {

    }
}

class Class3
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Class1 asd = new Class1();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't define a constructor with void as parameter. I think you are mixing the local `string` variable `abcd` with your method `abcd`

Comment: i think PingCompletedEventHandler is a delegate thats why it is able to take abc method as parameter , and Class1() constructor is a simple method thats why it is not working it you case

Comment: That constructor takes delegate. And thats a method you pass in is used as method group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating event-handlers you provide a pointer to method within the handlers constructor. This is not "a void", it is a delegate pointing to a method of type `void`.

The constructor therefor should look similar to:

```
delegate void HandlerMethod(objects s, PingCompletedEventArgs  e);
class PingCompletedEventHandler {
    PingCompletedEventHandler(HandlerMethod handler) { ... }
}
```

Now you can call this constructor with `new PingCompletedEventHandler(abc)` as `abc` is a method of type `void` expecting a param of type `object`and of of type `PingCompletedEventArgs`.

Further reading on delegates [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176.aspx)

EDIT: Since .NET 3.0 there is also the easier to read `Action`-type that can be used for methods that do not return anything (`void`). Thus you may also use `PingCompletedEventHandler(Action<object, PingCompletedEventArgs> handler)` instead of defining your own delegate.

Further EDIT: To get this to work for your test, your constructor for `Class1` should look like this: `Class1(Action<int> theAction)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want a Function as a Parameter of a Method or a Constructor then you have to use a [`Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

The easiest way is using a [`Action<...>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) if you have a Void return type or a [`Func<T, ...>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) if you have something else as return type.

In your case it will look like this:

```
public ClassConstructor(Action<YourParameter> myDelegate)
{
}
```

**For Example:**

This is a very simple function and you want to create a delegate of this:

```
private static int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

then you need a delegate that accepts an `int` as return type and two `int`s as parameters.

So you define a `Func<...>` like this and assign the original method:

```
Func<int, int, int> addDelegate = Add;
```

the usage is like using `Add` only with an other name:

```
var result = addDelegate(2, 5);
```